# Laravel 5.1 don't allow duplicate gecko name for current user

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have a situation with my app and I shall do my best to explain what it is i'm trying to do.

In my migration, I made my gecko `name` column unique (`$table->string('name')->unique()`). This obviously means that gecko names *must* be unique across the board for all users - this isn't what I want to do, I want to make sure that the current user cannot use the same name for another gecko.

For example:

> If user 1 makes a gecko called Bob and user 2 made a gecko called Bob that would be fine.
>
> If user 1 made a gecko called Bob, and then made *another* gecko
>   called Bob - This wouldn't be fine.

What is the best way/practice to make this work?

EDIT:

Store method:

```
public function store(GeckoRequest $request)
{

    Gecko::create($request->all());

    flash()->success('Success!', 'Your gecko has been created');

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think you should check this in `GeckoController` when the current user create a gecko:

```
public function store(GeckoRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    //if your geckoname input name is: geckoname
    if(!empty(Gecko::where('name', $data['geckoname'])->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->toArray())) {
        //do something if the gecko already exist
    } else {
        //if it doesn't exist, create the gecko
        Gecko::create($data);
        flash()->success('Success!', 'Your gecko has been created');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

In your `gecko table` the name doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: I'll give this a go in a second :)

Comment: I've updated my question with my store method, would you mind taking a look at what I have and make sure your code would still work okay?

Comment: Just so you know, this does work great but the answer from Luceos is cleaner and works just as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a unique index separately from the 1 field you're creating:

```
$table->unique(['user_id', 'name']);
```

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#creating-indexes

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Blueprint` class in your example variable `$table` you can also separately define a unique:

```
$table->unique(['user_id','name']);
```

It would also be wise to catch these constraints earlier than the database. So your logic (php) should also be aware about this, in order to do that you can use a [unique validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique):

```
'name' => "unique:geckos,name,NULL,id,user_id," . \Auth::user()->id
```

Comment: The gecko name should only be unique to the current user, not unique to the entire database. Is that what the `unique` method does?

Comment: The combined unique sets the combination as unique, so no entries may be added if user_id AND name are already an entry.